# Allow users to reload PHP FPM without Sudo

Tags: php, sudo, fpm

On our development servers, we allow multiple developers access to the server to `git pull` their changes. Normally this requires running `sudo systemctl reload php-fpm` (or sending `USR2`, etc.). However, we want to allow them to reload the changed code in PHP-FPM without needing `sudo`.

Way back when when I used to use Ruby, you could do exactly what I'm looking for by `touch`ing a file named `restart.txt` in the `tmp` directory.

Does PHP-FPM support anything like that?  Alternatively, is there anyway to allow the `reload` command (or any similar method of sending a `USR2`) without `sudo`?

Comment: Why do you need to restart/reload `php-fpm` after `git pull`?

Comment: You can achieve the same thing you have with ruby. I still have NO CLUE why you're reloading the FPM after git pull, it's not needed, your changes to php files will be executed regardless. But, to avoid further discussion: https://superuser.com/questions/181517/how-to-execute-a-command-whenever-a-file-changes - there, adjust to suit your needs.

Comment: @N.B. Because we turn off `opcache.validate_timestamps` for performance testing and benchmarking (and in production, though that's not relevant for this question), and the easiest way to clear the OpCache is with a reload.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll probably be there when whitelisting the command in your /etc/sudoers file:

Start by editing the sudoers file:

```
sudo visudo
```

Add the following config line:

```
user ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: systemctl reload php-fpm
```

> Replace *user* (at the beginning of the line) with the real username, for whom the command is executed.

This will privilege the user to call `sudo systemctl reload php-fpm` being executed as root (without password).

Comment: Note ALWAYS use `visudo` when editing the sudoers file, and the first `user` needs to be an actual username.

Comment: Note, you have to run the command with sudo in front of it.
Login as user `su user` then:
`sudo systemctl reload php-fpm`

Comment: Spent some time on it, visudo was saying invalid format, until I put `user ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl reload php-fpm` full path to executable command. Then it worked. Debian 9

Answer (score 2):

Or one can use:

```
user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/service php7.3-fpm *
```

Where `7.3` might change depending on the php version you have and `user` is your user.

Answer (score 0):

For beginners/googlers like me. **All steps** to restart or reload a service (edit where necessary)

1. install if not already `yum install sudo`
2. run `visudo` [this is how to edit it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12736351/exit-save-edit-to-sudoers-file-putty-ssh)
3. insert this `myUsername ALL=NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl restart httpd.service` (apache restart in my case, change to `reload php-fpm` if needed. above ans didn't work for some reason)
4. now `myUsername` can run something like `sudo /bin/systemctl restart httpd.service` [note sudo](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1012013/let-normal-user-restart-service-with-etc-sudoers)